# be avenged (in the passive voice)

Tags: grammar

A quote from Oxford Advanced Learer's Dictionary of Current English:

**avenge** *vt*
 get or take vengeance for: *~ an insult; ~ oneself / be ~d on an enemy* (*for* an injury, etc). *He ~d his father’s death upon the murderer*, punished the murderer.

My question is:
Why does 'be avenged' (in the passive voice, though) mean 'get or take vengeance' (in the active voice)?
Why is 'avenge' used in the passive voice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone avenges your injury or insult for instance, ***you will be avenged***, that is, you will be the "beneficiary" of revenge.

From: [Divinity Compromised: A Study...](https://books.google.it/books?id=LXCdHC0qsPUC&pg=PA93&dq=%22be%20avenged%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5y8iVkeHZAhVLOBQKHXNfC8UQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22be%20avenged%22&f=false):

> A man who is angry will want reparation made for the injury and some amends, and punishment meted out, ***so that he may be avenged***.

From [Crime and Punisshment in Ancient Rome](https://books.google.it/books?id=nquIAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%22be%20avenged%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3jJCMkuHZAhWHwxQKHQfMBMM4FBDoAQhBMAU#v=onepage&q=%22be%20avenged%22&f=false):

> In primitive society a ***wrong was a private matter to be avenged*** by direct retaliation by the victim or, if he had not survived, by his family

Comment: Thank you very much, user5768790.                                                         Is the way of saying possible?  That is, someone avenged me, so I was avenged by someone.

Comment: @AuAg - yes, both constructions are correct. See see for a few usage examples: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avenged+me%2CI+was+avenged&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavenged%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20avenged%3B%2Cc0